# Server-side validation for CreateUserWizard

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-membership, createuserwizard

I am using the built-in asp.net membership framework. I created a registration page and set up client-side validation with some custom validators, validating through jQuery AJAX to a web service and the client-side validation works ok. I have two issues:

1. Even when the client-side validation fails, the continue button still works. How do I disable it?
2. I don't want to count on client-side validation. How do I go about implementing server-side validation in the CreateUserWizard? Can you point me at some specific tutorial? I failed to find one.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use event [`CreatingUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.createuserwizard.creatinguser.aspx).

Markup:

```
<asp:CreateUserWizard runat="server" CreatingUser="wizard_CreatingUser" />
```

Code:

```
protected void wizard_CreatingUser (object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = ((CreateUserWizard)sender).UserName.Contains("!@#$%^&");
}
```

Comment: @abatishchev - That is more or less what I was looking for, but how do I invalidate the control so the right error message is displayed?

Comment: @Elad: Than I recommend you to expand CreateUserWizard into table and use CustomValidator against one of text fields

Comment: @abatishchev - I already expanded it to a template and used a table. I'm just not sure how I go about the server-side validation. The client-side validation is already working.

Comment: @Elad: Use [CustomValidator.ServerValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.servervalidate.aspx) event to perform other-validators-like but server-side validation

Comment: @abatishchev - So aside from implementing the validation in a seperate function for each validator control, I also need to revalidate the entire form in CreatingUser?

Comment: @Elad: If server-side validation will be enough, I think you can skip CreatingUser. This event is for some global, not local specific (like input) validation, e.g. system consistence, etc

Comment: Thank you! I'll go with that. Once last thing. How do I stop the CreatingUser event from firing if the controls don't validate client / server side?

Comment: @Elad: If I understood you correctly, CreateUserWizard will not create a user (and not fire the event) if any of validators on a page will fail. Did I?

Comment: @abatishchev - I have not put any server-side validation in yet, but for client-side validation it goes through (and fires the event) even if the client-side validation fails.

Comment: @Elad: Very strange. Take a look [here](http://pastebin.com/wqxejhf0), that works in some my web app project. Client-side validation doesn't allow user to be created

Comment: @abatishchev - I just checked. I have a compare validator to check password and password confirmation and the user is created even if the passwords don't match. I'm guessing this has to do with the wizard needing only the password field "officialy" (Hope you understand what I'm trying to say :))

Comment: Ok. Got it going now. I just didn't have the submit button on the same ValidationGroup as the rest of the controls. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Please look on the following tutorials for full information about the CreateUserWizard:
[Customizing the CreateUserWizard Control](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020103243/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070506-1.aspx).

Another helpful tutorial can be found here: [Customizing ASP.NET's CreateUserWizard Control To Display a Fixed Set of Security Questions](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153413/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/050609-1.aspx)